# Using a SELECT statement to return a row where a DateTime column = variable of type Date?

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, ado.net, oledb

I am using OleDb, trying to do this:

```
Dim d as Date = DateSerial(Year(rptDate), Month(rptDate), 1 - 1)

Dim conn as OleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr)
Dim cm as OleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand()

conn.Open()
cm.Connection = conn
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = " & d
```

Okay, so I know it returns 1 row because I'm staring at it in SQL Server. Here is what I've tried so far for the query in the last line, none work:

```
"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = " & d
"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = " & d.toString("G")
"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '" & d & "'"
"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '" & d.toString("G") & "'"
"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '#" & d & "#'"
"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = #" & d & "#" 'These last 2 with toString
```

I have also tried:

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = ?"
cm.Parameters.Add(d)

cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = ?"
cm.Parameters.Add(d.toString("G"))

cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '?'"
cm.Parameters.Add(d.toString("G"))

cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '?'"
cm.Parameters.Add(d)
```

Clearly I am missing something here, help? I know that `d` is the same date as the one in SQL server, specifically `3/31/2011 12:00:00 AM`.

Comment: What is the datatype of ReportDate in the DB?

Comment: the best way to "play" with dates in SQL is to format it as `yyyy-mm-dd`, so you'll avoid day/month conflicts. so you can do `Dim ds As String = d.Year & "-" & d.Month & "-" & d.Day` and then in sql : `"SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate >= '" & ds & "' AND ReportDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '" & ds & "')"`

Comment: Assuming your sql version is 2008 or higher, you better use `Date` data type unless you need the time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your query as stated is asking "give me all the entries for exactly midnight on this date".

Something like this should hopefully work:

```
cm.CommandText = "DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME; SET @MyDate = ?; SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate >= @MyDate AND ReportDate < DateAdd(day,1,@MyDate);"
cm.Parameters.Add(d)
```

This will return all entries on or after midnight of the date and before midnight of the next day.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = ?"
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParamName", d)
```

Depending on your provider, you may need to use named parameters:

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = @date"
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", d)
```

Comment: SQLOLEDB is the Provider in the connection string. The first one has no errors just like the ones in the OP, it just doesn't return anything when I know there is a row. The second returns an error about having to declare the scalar variable @date.

Comment: You probably have a slightly different time; the first code should work.  Try `>` and `<`.  Is there a reason you aren't using SqlClient?

Comment: No particular reason, this project was half done and I inherited it so I have been using OleDb. I dont think > or < will give me what I want, the ReportDate is the PK in the DB, I only want the row with the mm/dd/yyyy equal to `d`.

Comment: I know, but they will prove that your problem is that the date isn't _exactly_ equal.  (probably in the time portion)  You may want to write `d.Date`

Comment: I think I found the problem... so there are 4 dates for 2011 in the Database, one in each of Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr. When I do a query with `DATEPART(year, ReportDate) = 2011`, it brings three results, not four. It skips the Mar one, which is the one that I need right now. Wtf?

Answer (score 0):

Try using another date format in your SQL such as:

```
Cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '" & d.toString("mm/dd/yyyy") & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to create your date variable (d) as the day before the rptDate value *(ie. with a day of zero (1-1))* ?

This *(below)* will get you your record (assuming the record has no time part).

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = '" & d.toString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & "'"
```

*(The explicit date format is unambiguous, whereas "G" is not.)*

...or...

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE ReportDate = @date"
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", d)
```